# how to know the method to execute in extends on Java?

Tags: java

this is my Class A <- B <- C

```
class A {   
    void f ( A a ) { System . out . println ( " AA " );}
    void f ( C c ) { System . out . println ( " AC " );}
}
class B extends A {
    void f ( B b ) { System . out . println ( " BB " );}
}
class C extends B {
    void f ( A a ) { System . out . println ( " CA " );}
    void f ( C c ) { System . out . println ( " CC " );}
}
```

when I implement my main with the flowing Code I don't understand the result

```
public class app {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        A aa = new A ();
        B bb = new B ();
        A ac = new C ();
        A ab = new B ();
        B bc = new C ();            
        C cc = new C ();

        aa.f ( ac );
        bb.f ( ac );
        ab.f ( bb );
        bb.f ( ac );
        bb.f ( cc );

    }
}
```

the result is

```
 AA 
 AA 
 AA 
 AA 
 CA //Edit : AC instead of CA
```

I do not understand how Java found these results

please there are anyone here can explain the result ?

Comment: Can you please be more clear as to what you do not understand?

Comment: so which result don't you understand ?

Comment: This is a mix of overrides (subclass redefines the same method) and overloads (same method name but different/more specialized parameters). I'd guess your problems in understanding are with overloads so look that up.

Comment: I don't understand how to find the result without using Eclipse ? @npinti

Comment: You would need to look into polymorphism.

Comment: Just have `f` print its class name, then run it and see what happens.

Comment: Also, why "without using Eclipse"? That seems really arbitrary.

Comment: You probably have a typo in the last example. `bb.f(cc)` cant yield `CA` as `bb` is not a `C`. The result is `AC`.

Comment: @Zabuza thank you I corrected  the issu

Comment: @npinti thenks then it is polymorthism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method overview

Let's take a look at your example step by step. You have three classes, if we list all their methods (including overloads and inherited methods), you have:

```
class A:
    void f (A a) -> prints "AA" // #1
    void f (C c) -> prints "AC" // #2

class B:
    // from A
    void f (A a) -> prints "AA" // #3
    void f (C c) -> prints "AC" // #4

    // from B, overload
    void f (B b) -> prints "BB" // #5

class C:
    // from B
    void f (B b) -> prints "BB" // #6

    // from C, overrides methods from A
    void f (A a) -> prints "CA" // #7
    void f (C c) -> prints "CC" // #8
```

So your `B` class defines a new **overloaded** variant which accepts `B`. The `C` class inherits everything from `A` and `B` and **overrides** the two methods of `A`.

---

### Explanation

Now to your tests:

```
aa.f(ac); // AA
bb.f(ac); // AA
ab.f(bb); // AA
bb.f(ac); // AA
bb.f(cc); // CA
```

Your naming convention means that the actual instance is of the right characters type, while you refer to it through a variable of the left characters type. So `ab` is actually an instance of the class `B` and is referred to by a variable which is allowed to refer to `A` types.

Knowing this makes understanding the results quite easy. First example:

```
aa.f(ac); // AA
```

We have an instance of type `A`, in a variable of type `A`. The argument is of type `C`, in a variable of type `A`. Very important, note that the type of the variable will be used to determine which overload to choose from. So from `#1` and `#2`, Java chooses `#1`, since `ac` is in a variable of type `A`, not `C`. Since `#1` is used, the output is `"AA"`.

The exact same happens for the next three calls, although the third call is again interesting:

```
ab.f(bb); // AA
```

Although `ab` is actually a `B` instance, so it has a `void f(B b)` (`#5`) printing `"BB"`, we see `"AA"`. That is because `ab` is again in a variable of type `A`. So the compiler takes a look at the methods `A` offers. The only applicable method is `f(A a)` (`#1`), since `ab` is definitely not a `C`. So it uses again `#1` and prints `"AA"`.

---

### Typo in last example

With your last example there is something wrong. I guess you made a typo, since the code would output `"AC"`, not `"CA"`:

```
bb.f(cc); // AC
```

The reason is simple. `bb` is of type `B`, and also its variable. So we can choose from `B`s methods (and the one inherited from `A`). The argument is of type `C`, same for its variable. So we call method `#4`, printing `"AC"`.

---

### Type overview

Here are the actual type-situations which are relevant in the end:

```
A.f(A); // AA, #1
B.f(A); // AA, #3
A.f(B); // AA, #1
B.f(A); // AA, #3
B.f(C); // AC, #4
```

---

### JLS definition

The rules how Java determines which methods to call are clearly defined in the **Java Language Specification**. You can read it, if you are interested. The relevant chapter is [15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). In particular [15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1) and [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Some excerpts:

> The class [...] is searched for all member methods that are potentially applicable to this method invocation; members inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces are included in this search.
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the **most specific method** is chosen.